# How to reshape data delimited with whitespaces but with headers that can't be delimited by white space

Tags: python, pandas

I've a simulation result for an antenna result as it can be found in [here](https://pastebin.com/bDDigqHd)

You can see that I need to reshape this data so three things happen:

- The headers are kept on the format `Var(extraInfo)[unit]` where the parenthesis can be sometimes optional as seen from the first column and third column
- The second row is removed (the `---`)
- The data then is properly assigned to each of the header columns, which can be done easily through a `delim_whitespace=True)

The first and second topic seems the confusing to me (where to start at least).

And I also had a workaround so far that requires me to type this all every time (I'd like to make this more automatize hence the post). I basically ignore the two first rows and then manually enter the variables name

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Results.txt', skiprows=2, delim_whitespace=True, lineterminator='\n',header  =None)
df = df.drop(8, axis=1)
df.rename(columns={0: 'V1', 1: 'V2', 2: 'V3', 3: 'V4', 4: 'V5',5: 'V6', 6: 'V7', 7: 'V8'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Don't post images of data, code, error, etc. Copy/paste as text. Post [mre] of the code you tried so far.

Comment: split the header at `]`, then add it back

Comment: Extremely hard to say, the screenshot is rather bad. But it lools a bit like a fixed-width formatted file, so you could try [`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html).

Comment: Thanks all for the answers, I've since received some help from people who are used to process this kind of data and moved from `pandas` to `numpy`. I hope I can help people with my answer and I excuse myself for not formulating the question well at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since worked on this code. You can retrieve an example of the dataset [here](https://pastebin.com/bDDigqHd). Paste on your notepad and save as a `.txt` to reproduce. As I wanted to have freedom to use the different columns I decided to move from `pandas` towards `numpy` which made things a bit easier to play with (specially since all the processing ends up happening with numpy arrays).

```py
import numpy as np

myArray = np.loadtxt('myFile.txt', skiprows=2)
```

If you look into the created array you can see you can select the columns as I wished for initially by doing:

```
myArray[:,0]
Out[99]: array([-180., -179., -178., ...,  177.,  178.,  179.])
```